# R - How to add data to a new column by subset conditions?

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to add values to a new column based on values in another column.  Using the iris data as an example my basic logic is "If iris$Sepal.Length > 5, then iris$size == 'TRUE'".

```
> head(iris, 2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Using the iris data as an example my basic logic is "If iris$Sepal.Length > 5, then iris$size == 'TRUE'" to produce:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species size
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   TRUE
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   NA
```

I can subset the data, but can't get the syntax to pass a value back.  Something like this?

```
subset(iris, iris$Sepal.Length >= 5) %>% iris$size == 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
iris$size[iris$Sepal.Length>=5] <- TRUE
```

This basically reads as "put TRUE into iris$size for those rows where iris$Sepal.Length is equal or greater than 5".

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this using the `ifelse` statement

```
iris$Size <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Length >= 5, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`.  The output of a logical expression is `TRUE/FALSE`.  It is better not to create a character output

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
    mutate(size = Sepal.Length >=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
iris$size <- iris$Sepal.Length >= 5
```

Or if you want to go down the tidyverse route

```
iris %>% mutate(size = Sepal.Length >= 5)
```